# Animate view out of screen goes wrong ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a view controller that contains two views. What I need is that after the view controller has been pushed, the view on top (_sidepanelview) moves to the left disappearing of the screen.

Here is what I wrote:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect newsidepanelviewposition = _sidepanelview.frame;
    newsidepanelviewposition.origin.x = -_sidepanelview.frame.size.width;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        _sidepanelview.frame = newsidepanelviewposition;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Done!");

    }];
}
```

The problem is that when I run the app, after the view controller been pushed, **the view _sidepanelview disappears from the screen and appears again to the center of the screen coming from the right side** instead of moving to the left from x=0 to x= -_sidepanelview width disappearing from the screen.

What I'm doing wrong?

Note: I did the app with auto layout unchecked and the animation worked fine, but using it with the auto layout turned on it freaks out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your `note` suggests, Auto Layout is the "culprit".
Your views have constraints that are periodically enforced by the AutoLayout engine. When you alter the `frame` of a view, the frame changes, but not the view's layout constraints. When the next cycle of `layoutSubviews` occurs, your views position and size (i.e. `frame`) will be reset to what the constraints dictate.

If you want to include AutoLayout for that view/viewcontroller, use constraint changes to perform the animation.

The golden rule here is, *`setFrame` is the antithesis of AutoLayout.*

**Sample code**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    _sidePanelLeadingSpace.constant = -_sidepanelview.frame.size.width; // 1 

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // 2


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Done!");

    }];
}
```

1. Have a reference, `_sidePanelLeadingSpace` (`NSLayoutConstraint`), to the leading space constraint of `_sidepanelview`, for e.g., as an IBOutlet.
2. Alter the constraint's `constant` and layout the view by calling `layoutIfNeeded` in an animation block

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the setFrame to contradict what constraints in storyboard dictate?

Comment: What I meant was, `setFrame` is by nature contradictory to AutoLayout, because frame updates do not update constraints. If you're using AutoLayout, don't use `setFrame` - always just update constraints. 

I have updated my answer with some sample code.

Comment: In my case I just use the constraints to center the _sidepanelview in X and Y in the container. How should I update the constraint? I see that you used for example the leadingSpace constraint.

Comment: Okay, in that case, create an `IBOutlet` for the centerX constraint. Setting it to "minus sidePanel width" will offset the centerX by that distance.

Comment: You're welcome! :) To learn more on the topic, I'd highly recommend the WWDC talks of the last 3 years talking about AutoLayout, especially the early ones!